# CrawlSpider callback not working, next page is retrieved once

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to perform a horizontal crawling -- starting from the first page and move until reaching the last page. The code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy_project.items import metacriticItem
import datetime

# xpaths
main_xpath = '//div[@class = "title_bump"]//td[@class = "clamp-summary-wrap"]'
mt_url_xpath = './a/@href'

class MovieUrlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'movie_url'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/score/metascore/all',
    )

    # rules for horizontal crawling
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@rel="next"]'), 
             callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # list of items we want
        main = response.xpath(main_xpath)
        
        for i in main:
            # create the loader using the response
            l = ItemLoader(item = metacriticItem(), selector = i)
            
            # key
            l.add_xpath('mt_url', mt_url_xpath)
            
            # housekeeping fields
            l.add_value('url', response.url)
            l.add_value('spider', self.name)
            l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
            
            yield l.load_item()
```

This script did not parse any item and it return the following message:

```
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.metacritic.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/score/metascore/all> (referer: None)
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.metacritic.com': <GET https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/score/metascore/all?page=1>
2021-05-12 02:22:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Your requests are being filtered because of `allowed_domains = ['web']`

Comment: @stranac would you mind explaining why I need to specify the `allowed_domains` for this case? I usually just use `web` for scraping tasks with `scrapy.Spider` module and it works fine.

Comment: @voravich-ch You must not specify it, it's optional. Just check out documentation https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains